# Redirect to a specific site after login via spring security

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have coded a sign up page:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class='fheader'>
            <g:message code="springSecurity.login.header" />
        </div>

        <g:if test='${flash.message}'>
            <div class='login_message'>
                ${flash.message}
            </div>
        </g:if>

        <form action='${postUrl}' method='POST' id='loginForm'
            class="form-signin" autocomplete='off'>


            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" name='j_username'
                id='username' placeholder="Username" /> <input type='password'
                class="form-control" name='j_password' id='password'
                placeholder="Password" />

            <p id="remember_me_holder">
                <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox'
                    name='${rememberMeParameter}' id='remember_me'
                    <g:if test='${hasCookie}'>checked='checked'</g:if> /> <label
                    class="checkbox" for='remember_me'><g:message
                        code="springSecurity.login.remember.me.label" /></label>
            </p>

            <!--            <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox"
                value="remember-me"> Remember me
            </label> -->
            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type='submit'
                id="submit" value='${message(code: "springSecurity.login.button")}' />
        </form>

    </div>
    <!-- /container -->

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    <!--
    (function() {
        document.forms['loginForm'].elements['j_username'].focus();
    })();
    // -->
</script>
```

Into the page I have integrated the `spring-security-core:2.0-RC2` plugin.

However, when I start the server and try to log in with my created users I get nothing. No notification that it worked, no redirect.

In fact I just want to redirect to my main page mapped as `"/"(view:"/index")` in the `URLMappings.groovy`

How to change the redirect?

I really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your config file:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl="/someController/someAction"
```